# Is there a "w" sound in 谁 like Shwéi or is it just Shéi?

Tags: mandarin, pronunciation

When I listen to native speakers I can sometimes hear a "w" sound in 谁

Like it was "shwei". Or is it just "Shéi"?

Which is correct?

Comment: And also 这(zhe/zhei).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]. Note the "ui" and "[image]" produce the sound of "W". You can listen the pronunciation [here](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%B0%81).

Answer (score 2):

In Mandarin, it's acceptable for 谁 to be pronounced either "Shéi" and "Shuí"; I think you're hearing the second pronunciation here.

> [image: photo of 现代汉语词典]

Answer (score 0):

It’s good to catch it. In many northern areas normally people say “ni shu shei li?”. (你说谁哩？）(not the so called standard Chinese HanYv pronunciation). but in the school students would read “shu-ei shi ni de baba?”. (谁是你的爸爸？” It is actually a combination of “shu “ (书）and “ei “（诶）。

Answer (score 0):

shui is more formal. shei is more conversational.